# How are OCR training datasets constructed?

Tags: cnn, computer-vision, ocr, faster-rcnn

For the sake of concreteness: let's suppose that the word "OCR" refers to any OCR system build on an R-CNN architecture. Similarly, in aims of simplicity, let's declare that we are interested in reading digits between 0 and 100.

**Question:** ***How should I construct a dataset (given the aforementioned goal and architecture) ?***

My understanding is that I need to collect images of all the digits from 1 to 100 and label them with its corresponding digit. Is this premise correct?

My struggle is that I can't fully understand how this seemingly tedious procedure is generalized to OCR that read more general types of characters (language-characters for example or if I generalize the problem to detect the numbers from 0 to $10^{10}$).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

OCR used to recognize letters uses a different training dataset than OCR for digits. One that contains, well, letters.

Similarly, if you have to recognize a number with a lot of digits, you simply need to recognize each one of them. You don't actually train (most times) with numbers up to a hundred, you only train 0-9.

Generalization in such models refers to how well the model can detect your handwritten a if it was trained on my handwritten a, etc. It can't possibly recognize something as an "a" when all it has seen is 0-9.

Edit:
If you are mostly worried about the actual construction of the labeled dataset (finding images and labeling them), yes it is a very tedious process. But someone (a human) has to teach the machine.